# How do I setup access to shared folders using certificates?

Tags: windows-10, certificate, shared-folders

I have a simple home network with several computers.
While connected to the home network I want my work laptop to have access to shares in other computers, but I don't want to save my home credentials in the work computer.

How can I setup access using certificates in a similar way to ssh access with authorized_keys?
I.e. generate a certificate in the work computer and add it to the user account in the home computer.